# Fail Install Kivy on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to run Kivy application on my Raspberry Pi 4 but when i run it, it returns:

```
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
```

i used https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/doc/sources/installation/installation-rpi.rst#raspberry-pi-1-4-installation to install environment.

How to fix it?

## Versions

- Python: 3.7.3
- OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- Kivy: v2.0.0rc1
- Cython: 0.29.10
- sdl2, etc. installed

## My Code

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
import os
os.environ['KIVY_VIDEO']='ffpyplayer'
os.environ['KIVY_WINDOW'] = 'sdl2'

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  MyApp().run()
```

## Result

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-01-30_13.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc1, git-Unknown, 20200130
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2(['text_pango'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - RuntimeError: b''
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 70, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 981, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 290, in create_window
    self.get_gl_backend_name())
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 112, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 74, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Python 3.6 and Windows 7. Works on Windows 10 also.
this solution solve the problem in most cases :

1. Right click on This PC then open Properties .
2. Go to Advanced system settings .
3. Click on Environment Variables .
4. Click on New in User variables for --- .
5. Put KIVY_GL_BACKEND in Variable name .
6. Put angle_sdl2 in Variable value .
7. Restart Python .

Here is a YouTube video showing these steps : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATK9w2AiDeM

If this does not fix it-

Install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 and see if that fixes it? The only other thing I can think of is the user thing you mentioned. Windows could be blocking something due to user permissions? Make sure the python you use is installed for the current user.

I would suggest that you completely uninstall kivy (including dependencies), and then make a new virtual environment and then install kivy to it and try again.